# Prestashop: Add a text in the order payment page

Tags: php, controller, prestashop, payment

I 'm trying to customize the order payment page (step 5),
it's the page shown just before the order confirmation.

The text to add in this page is a simple sentence that include the variables "order-ID" and the "total amount".
Example od sentence to add: "Your order number is: XXX and the amount is: YYY"

I guess that the first thing to do is to add the sentence and the 2 variables in the controller (probabily in the file "OrderController.php" or "OrderDetailController.php" Im not sure...)

Then the last step should be to add {$my_sentence} in the "order-payment.tpl" file?

I'm familiar with PHP, i just need to understand what files/function i need to edit.
Could someone please help me?

PS: My prestashop version is the 1.4, as payment module there is paypal pro and wire.

Answer (score 0):

I stricly recommend that you modify anything using a module :

1. Create a simple module (look up simple module tutorials on the web)
2. Find exec() function in Hook.php, use error_log($hook_name) to find out which hooks are executed.
3. Regsiter the hook you selected in your module's install function. Then create a function `public funtion hook{HOOK_NAME}($args){ error_log(print_r($args, 1)); }`
4. You should find a hook that adds things to that page (adds display).

There is on problem though. I believe that the order is not formed until it is confirmed (in the enxt step). So the only thing you will probably have available in that page is `Cart` and `Customer` data.